# Entire functions for which the absolute value is the sum of functions of $x$ and $y$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find all entire function $f(z)= u+iv $ satisfying  : $|f(z)|^2= g(x)^2 + h(y)^2$, where $g$ and $h$ are differentiable functions of one variable.

I tried to differentiate both sides, and use Cauchy-Riemann equations to solve the system and find  $u$ and $v$, but it's not really working so I really appreciate any hint and help you might give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function that is the sum of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$ has zero mixed partial derivative $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}$ (and conversely). This partial can be related to Wirtinger derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial z^2}-\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \bar z^2}
=\frac14 \left(\frac{\partial  }{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial  }{\partial y} \right)^2 - \frac14 \left(\frac{\partial  }{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial  }{\partial y} \right)^2 = -i\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}
$$
So, 
$$\frac{\partial^2 |f|^2}{\partial z^2} = \frac{\partial^2 |f|^2}{\partial \bar z^2}$$
Write $|f|^2=f\bar f$ and differentiate, using the fact that $f$ is holomorphic: 
$$f'' \bar f = f \overline{f''} $$
It follows that the (meromorphic) function $f''/f$ is real and therefore identically constant.

The solutions of the equation $f''=Cf$ are well-known: $Ae^{\alpha z}+Be^{-\alpha z}$ where $\alpha ^2=C$, as well as $f(z)=Az+B$ if $C=0$. Note that $\alpha $ may be complex.

The preceding describes all entire functions such that $|f(z)|^2=G(x)+H(y)$ for some $G,H$. Since $|f|^2\ge 0$, the summands $G,H$ [can also be taken nonnegative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1592211).

It remains to take the square root. In general, a smooth nonnegative function need not be the square of a smooth function ([reference](https://mathoverflow.net/q/105438)). But a nonnegative *real-analytic* functions $G$ is the square of some real-analytic function $g$. Indeed, the zeros of $G$ form a discrete set and near each zero, $G$ is represented as $G(x)=(x-a)^{2k} r(x)$ with $r(a)> 0$. Then $G(x) = \pm (x-a)^k \sqrt{r(x)}$ works locally, and one can choose $\pm$ signs consistently.

Comment: Thanks, added the linear functions.

Comment: OP also required both summands to be squares though. This does not follow and for $|\sin(z)|^2$ it isn't the case (one summand being $-\cos(2x)/2$.)

Comment: A good point, I didn't consider this.  Edited.  Does it still not work for $|\sin z|^2$ if you shift a constant from one summand to the other?... Well, now that the form of functions is established, I'm inclined to leave the positivity alone.

Comment: Actually, it seems to work always: see my edit.

Comment: Yes, had to distribute the constant sensibly. Brilliant, very nice!