# If a nonnegative function of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ can be written as $\sum g_k(x_k)$, then the summands can be taken nonnegative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,\infty)$ is a function that can be written in the form
>   $$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=g_1(x_1)+g_2(x_2)+\dots+g_n(x_n) $$
>   Can we also choose all $g_k$ to be nonnegative?

This self-answered question is motivated by [Entire functions for which the absolute value is the sum of functions of $x$ and $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1546192) where a special case of the above is needed.

A special case when $f$ attains its minimum at some $x^*$ is easy, since $x_k^*$ is then the minimum of all $g_k$, and we can add/subtract the constants to make $g_k(x_k^*)\ge 0$. But of course, $f$ need not attain a minimum in general.

Comment: Another special case was mentioned [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428662/the-implication-of-zero-mixed-partial-derivatives-for-multivariate-functions-mi?lq=1), without a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By keeping all but one of the co-ordinates of $(x_1,...,x_n)$ fixed, we have (-$\infty <L_i=\inf_x g_i(x))$ for each $i.$  Now for any $e>0$ : For each $i$ take $x_i$ satisfying  $g_i(x_i)=L_i+d_i/n$  where $0\leq d_i<e.$ Then $$-e\leq f(x_1,...,x_n)-e=\sum_1^n (L_i+(d_i-e)/n)<\sum_1^nL_i.$$ Since $e$ can be arbitrarily small we have, therefore, $$0\leq \sum_1^nL_i=K.$$ Now let $g^*_1=K-L_1+g_1$ and let $g^*_i=-L_i+g_i$ for $i>1.$

Comment: Or if you like, let $g_i=(K/n)-L_i+g_i$ for every $i$.

Comment: Yes, I was overcomplicating things. The matter boils down to $\inf f = \sum \inf g_k$ because the infimum distributes over such a sum (independent variables).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Given $\epsilon>0$, let $x^*$ be a point such that $f(x^*)\ge \inf f - \epsilon$. By considering the restriction of $f$ onto the $k$th coordinate line through $x^*$, it follows that for every $k$, 
$$
g_k(t)\ge g_k(x^*_k) - \epsilon,\quad \forall \ t\in\mathbb{R}
$$
By adding a suitable constant $c_k$ to each $g_k$ (with $\sum c_k=0$ of course), we can arrange so that 
$$g_1(x_1^*)+c_1=\cdots=g_n(x_n^*)+c_n = \frac{1}{n}f(x^*) \ge \frac1n (\inf f - \epsilon)\ge -\frac{\epsilon}{n}$$
Thus, 
$$\inf (g_k+c_k) \ge -\frac{n+1}{n}\epsilon,\quad k=1,\dots,n\tag{1}$$

The proof concludes by compactness. For each $\epsilon>0$ we have a tuple $(c_1(\epsilon),\dots,c_n(\epsilon))$ as above, achieving $(1)$. As $\epsilon\to 0$, the numbers $c_k(\epsilon)$ stay bounded: $(1)$ bounds them from below, and the condition $\sum c_k=0$ bounds them from above. So we have a limit $(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ along some sequence $\epsilon_j$, and this limit yields 
$$\inf (g_k+c_k) \ge 0 ,\quad k=1,\dots,n $$

Comment: I meant to edit my answer and accidentally clicked on Normal Human's answer. I made no changes to it.